# Javascript instanceof weird behavior

Tags: javascript, prototype, instanceof

Why does it returns false?

```
function f(){ return f; }
new f() instanceof f; // Prints false instead of true
```

As I understand, in this particular case `instanceof` should check something like:

`newObj.__proto__ === f.prototype`.

And `newObj.__proto__` should be set automatically on `new f()` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructor functions implicitly return `this`.
`this` *is* an instance of the constructor function and so, if you return `this` the function will evaluate to true.

You do *not* return `this`. You return `f` which is not an instance of the constructor, thus the expression returns `false`.

Comment: and I think when you write new it's better practice to write new F() instanceof f;

Comment: @EndritShala JavaScript is case sensitive, so `F` is not the same symbol as `f`

Comment: @V_B Awesome, I'm glad. Please consider marking this answer as accepted if it answered your question :)

Comment: @Petrichor done. There is a limitation - I can't accept your answer within first 15 minutes